# MySQL MLM downline select query for the very first user

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am running a select query to get the downline members. It works nice for all users except the first user.

Here is my sql fiddle with data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/036c5e/2

I want to get the downline members for user_id 1

I am running the query like this

```
SELECT 
            t1.user_id AS lev0, 
            t2.user_id as lev1, 
            t3.user_id as lev2, 
            t4.user_id as lev3,
            t5.user_id as lev4,
            t6.user_id as lev5,
            t7.user_id as lev6,
            t8.user_id as lev7,
            t9.user_id as lev8

        FROM members AS t1

            LEFT JOIN members AS t2 ON t2.boss = t1.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t3 ON t3.boss = t2.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t4 ON t4.boss = t3.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t5 ON t5.boss = t4.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t6 ON t6.boss = t5.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t7 ON t7.boss = t6.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t8 ON t8.boss = t7.user_id
            LEFT JOIN members AS t9 ON t9.boss = t8.user_id
            WHERE t1.user_id = 1
            order by t1.created_at
```

If I replace `t1.user_id =2` or any others it works nicely. Anyone please help. Thanks..

**EDIT**
I want to get the user_id of boss 1. boss 1 is the starter. So I want to get all his downlines members. How can I do this? Many thanks.

Comment: There is no record with `user_id = 1` in `members`... So what do you expect to get?

Comment: Edited my question. Actually I want to get downline members of `boss=1`

Comment: Then change the WHERE CLAUSE to `WHERE t1.boss = 1`

Comment: ah ok got it . It works. I changed where user_id = 1 to where boss = 1 and it worked. :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
WHERE t1.user_id = 1
```

To

```
WHERE t1.boss = 1
```